# Three related Lists to a Tree like structure in C#

Tags: c#, linq, treeview

I have three lists. Id of LevelOne is Parent of LevelTwo and Id of LevelTwo is parent of Level3.

```
LevelOne
{
    Level
    {
        Id = "ABC",
        Desc = "Some desc"
    },
    Level
    {
        Id = "DEF",
        Desc = "Some desc"
    },
    Level
    {
        Id = "PQR",
        Desc = "Some desc"
    },
    Level
    {
        Id = "XYZ",
        Desc = "Some desc"
    }
}

LevelTwo
{
    Level
    {
        Id = "123A",
        Parent = "ABC",
        Desc = "Some Desc"
    },
    Level
    {
        Id = "123B",
        Parent = "ABC",
        Desc = "Some Desc"
    },
    Level
    {
        Id = "123C",
        Parent = "PQR",
        Desc = "Some Desc"
    },
    Level
    {
        Id = "123D",
        Parent = "XYZ",
        Desc = "Some Desc"
    }
}

LevelThree
{
    Level
    {
        Id = "XYZ1",
        Parent = "123A",
        Desc = "Some Desc"
    },
    Level
    {
        Id = "XYZ2",
        Parent = "123A",
        Desc = "Some Desc"
    },
    Level
    {
        Id = "XYZ3",
        Parent = "123B",
        Desc = "Some Desc"
    },
    Level
    {
        Id = "XYZ4",
        Parent = "123D",
        Desc = "Some Desc"
    }
}
```

I am trying to consolidate these three lists into one list which will have a tree like structures of LevelOne Ids.

```
public class AllLevels
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Desc {get;set;}
    public bool HasChild {get;set;}
    public IList<AllLevels> {get;set;}
}
```

sample output would be something like this

```
AllLevels
{
    Level
    {
        Id = "ABC",
        Desc = "SomeDesc",
        HasChildLevel = true,
        childLevel = 
        {
            Id = "123A",
            Desc = "SomeDesc",
            hasChildLevel = true,
            ChildLevel =
            {
                Id = "XYZ1",
                Desc = "Some Desc",
                HasChildLevel = false
            },
            ChildLevel =
            {
                Id = "XYZ2",
                Desc = "Some Desc",
                HasChildLevel = false
            }
        },
        childLevel = 
        {
            Id = "123B",
            Desc = "SomeDesc",
            hasChildLevel = true,
            ChildLevel =
            {
                Id = "XYZ3",
                Desc = "Some Desc",
                HasChildLevel = false
            }
        }
    },
    Level
    {
        Id = "XYZ",
        Desc = "Some Desc",
        HasChildLevel = true
        ChildLevel =
        {
            Id = "123D",
            Desc = "Some Desc",
            HasChild = true,
            ChildLevel = 
            {
                Id = "XYZ4",
                Desc = "Some Desc",
                HasChild = false
            }
        }
    },
    Level
    {
        Id = "DEF",
        Desc = "Some Desc",
        HasChildLevel = false
    }
}
```

Is there a way through LINQ I can do this process without using nested foreach loops ? 
I have gone through many posts in Stackover flow but I am not able to find a technique to merge three related lists in to a hierarchy. 
If someone has a reference to website where I can get some idea that would also help.

Comment: have you looked at `SelectMany`?

Comment: Why do u want to avoid nested for-loops?
U can loop all once, and add all without parent to the first list, and then add child at each level via recursion with IList.FindAll(x=>x.Id == current.Parent.
This is just a nudge in the right direction. Recursion and Tree-structures are friends :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are never going more than three levels deep, then the below is a relatively readable solution.  But it isn't a generic solution to a generic problem.

```
        var result = levelOne
            .Select(l1 => new AllLevels
            {
                Id = l1.Id,
                Desc = l1.Desc,
                HasChild = levelTwo.Any(l2 => l2.Parent == l1.Id),
                Children = levelTwo.Where(l2 => l2.Parent == l1.Id)
                .Select(l2 => new AllLevels
                {
                    Id = l2.Id,
                    Desc = l2.Desc,
                    HasChild = levelThree.Any(l3 => l3.Parent == l2.Id),
                    Children = levelThree.Where(l3 => l3.Parent == l2.Id)
                    .Select(l3 => new AllLevels
                    {
                        Id = l3.Id,
                        Desc = l3.Desc,
                        HasChild = false,
                        Children = new List<AllLevels>()
                    })
                })
            });
```